# Validating a specific number of arguments (int) using scanf?

Tags: c, validation, input, scanf

I need to make a "connect 4" program with a grid based on user input. How can I detect the amount of ints scanned without any buffering, or "accepting" a short input without waiting for another argument? In this case, I want the user to enter 3 values at the start of the program.

```
 Example 1
 ./connectn.out 5 20
 Not enough arguments entered

 Example 2
 ./connectn.out 13 2 3 4 5
 Too many arguments entered
```

Comment: Why not declare `argv` and `argc` parameters in `main()`? Then you can determine if `argc` is equal to three. I suggest taking a look at [this](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) tutorial.

Comment: `scanf` is for program-prompted input.  What you're asking for is command-line arguments, which are quite different.  Just check `argc` to see how many were supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is argc and argv parameters. You can use argc for the argument count, and argv for the arguments itself.

Here is a sample code for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  // Check the argument count first
  if (argc != 4)
  {
    if (argc > 4)
    {
      printf("Too many arguments entered!\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Not enough arguments entered!\n");
    }
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    // Check a specific argument (-h)
    if (strcmp(argv[3], "-h") != 0)
    {
      printf("Invalid option!\n");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  printf("Hello World.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Note that in `./connectn.out 5 20` argc is 3. Because "connectn.out" also counts.

Here is some sample output:

```
./out 1 2
Not enough arguments entered!
./out 1 2 3 4
Too many arguments entered!
./out 1 2 -a
Invalid option!
./out 1 2 -h 4
Too many arguments entered!
./out 1 2 -h
Hello World.
```

Hope this helps.

Baris